# Conditionally order by another column

Tags: php, mysql

I query a database and order by a date column in the table and also by another column in another table. This is working perfectly.

`SELECT * FROM myTable1 LEFT JOIN myTable2 b ON myTable1.id = b.id WHERE myTable1.id !='foo' ORDER BY myTable1.dateColumn DESC, b.column2 ASC`

What I would like is to do is ORDER by `myTable1.dateColumn` ONLY if there is no value in `b.column2` for that particular record. As you can see from my above current implementation, it will always ORDER BY `myTable1.dateColumn` regardless.

Stackoverflow Suggested tag for this question is `mysql` but in fact I am using `mysqli`. It makes no difference for the purpose of this question.

Comment: It might be me, but I don't get your question. You either order your results, or not. How can you half-order your result? I don't think this makes sense? I guess you want to filter out certain rows. Why not do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can put CASE Statements inside of an `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable1
LEFT JOIN myTable2 b
    ON myTable1.id = b.id
WHERE myTable1.id != 'foo'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN b.column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, myTable1.dateColumn DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is putting the records that have b.column2 = NULL at the top, not the myTable1.dateColumn

Comment: I've adjusted the order by to account for that. Slightly different then original question, but this, I believe, is what you are looking for. Sort by b.column2 IS NULL then by datecolumn desc

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in the order part; something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 LEFT JOIN myTable2 b ON myTable1.id = b.id WHERE myTable1.id !='foo'
ORDER BY IF(b.column2 IS NULL,1,0),IF(b.column2 IS NULL,myTable1.dateColumn,NULL) DESC, b.column2 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, this is putting the records that have b.column2 = NULL at the top, not the myTable1.dateColumn

Comment: I've edited to put the column2 elements at the bottom.  This will sort by column2 and then after those elements by dateColumn for the elements with a NULL column2

Answer (score 0):

You should better provide some data sample and expected result, but so far you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 
LEFT JOIN myTable2 b 
ON myTable1.id = b.id 
WHERE myTable1.id !='foo' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN b.column2 IS NULL myTable1.dateColumn ELSE NULL END DESC, b.column2 ASC
```